# change foreground/background colors in eclipse dialogues

Tags: eclipse, background-foreground

I don't find the special setting to change the fore- & background colors of eclipse dialog, e.g. as in screenshot. I know where to find in general but this special one I don't know. Thanx for helping.

[image]

Comment: That looks like an issue of the Dark theme (on macOS?). Do you use the latest version of Eclipse (Eclipse Oxygen.1a)? There were some improvements in this version... (see [my video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8&t=460s))

Comment: Yes, latest Version, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200.  - OSX, I am using Zenburn template. but with default template (Dark) same problem. I have found a few settings for other color topics like annotations,... which helped for other problems I had. But this especially I can't find.

Comment: Is this also the case in the file rename dialog (_Refactor > Rename..._) or only in some dialogs?

Comment: yes also in Refactor->Rename. And I saw it in other corners but I cannot remember where... ;-(

Comment: In this case, it is a bug of the Eclipse platform. If [not yet reported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?longdesc=dark&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr&query_format=advanced), please [report it to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&version=4.7.1a&component=UI&op_sys=Mac%20OS%20X).

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=500562 Thanx, done!